# El URI solicitado no es valido para este comando FTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar cargar un archivo vía FTP, me sale el error

> El URI solicitado no es valido para este comando FTP.

Código:

```
FtpWebRequest resquest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(NombreServidor));
resquest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
resquest.Proxy = null;
resquest.UseBinary = true;
resquest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Usuario, Clave);

StreamReader ftpStream = new StreamReader(NombreCompletoArchivo);
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(NombreCompletoArchivo);
byte[] Contenido = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ftpStream.ReadToEnd());
ftpStream.Close();
resquest.ContentLength = Contenido.Length;

Stream requestStream = resquest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(Contenido, 0, Contenido.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse respuesta = (FtpWebResponse)resquest.GetResponse();
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error te lo manda debido a que en el método `.Create(new Uri(NombreServidor))` debes especificar y/o concatenar el nombre del archivo para que quede de esta forma:

```
FtpWebRequest resquest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(NombreServidor + "/" + NombreArchivo));
```

Donde en la variable `NombreArchivo` va la ruta completa así como el nombre del archivo.

**Fuente**: documentación oficial del método [FtpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (*en inglés*), sección *operations to upload a file to an FTP server.*

## Actualización

Debido al error que ahora te muestra:

> Error en el servidor Remoto: (530) No ha iniciado sesión.

La [documentación oficial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/200475/error-message-in-iis-530-user-username-cannot-log-in.-login-failed.) (en inglés) del error dice que se puede presentar por 4 causas:

- La configuración **Allow only anonymous connections security** ha sido desactivada en la consola de administración de Microsoft (MMC).
- El usuario no tiene activado el permiso **acceder localmente** en el administrador de usuarios.
- El usuario no tiene permisos para **acceder a la computadora desde la red**.
- El nombre del dominio no ha sido especificado en conjunto con el nombre del usuario (debe tener la forma **DOMINIO\nombreUsuario**)

Recomendación: revisa estos 4 puntos, dale un vistazo a la documentación oficial ya que ahí viene información más completa y como verás, todo se relaciona con el usuario y la contraseña, ahora el problema ha sido aislado y ya sabes qué corregir.

Comment: Gracias, ya el error no me sale, pero ahora me lo siguiente: ´Error en el servidor Remoto: (530) No ha iniciado sesión.´

Comment: @RamónZoquier ¿En qué línea de código te envía ese mensaje? También debes asegurar que las credenciales proporcionadas son válidas.

Comment: me la envía en esta línea: `Stream requestStream = resquest.GetRequestStream();`, pero las credenciales son válidas.

Comment: @RamónZoquier actualicé mi respuesta, dale una revisada y todo se relaciona con las credenciales proporcionadas :)

Comment: te aseguro que las credenciales que estoy usando son las correctas, imagino que tiene que ver con la configuración del puerto, o el protocolo de conexión SSL.  Sólo que no se como especificar esto en c#.